# Is my A/C circuit break worn out?

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning, circuit-breaker

My secondary A/C unit has been drawing too much current and trips the breaker. It has happened about 4 times.

Yesterday, I spent a bit of money to replace the whole A/C and furnace with one which is supposedly energy efficient. After the workers left having installed and check the new system, the breaker tripped again.

Do you think it's the circuit breaker that has weakened or the new system might be drawing still too much current?

I guess my question is does a circuit breaker get weak after being tripped several times?

It was pretty warm when I turned the breaker back on.
Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: What all is on the breaker that's tripping, and what make, model, and rating is the breaker?

Comment: Also, are you saying the breaker was warm when you turned it back on?

Comment: If the breakers warm with the new system then you probably have a problem with the bresker box.  It's possible the buss and braker a poor connection and is generating heat, or it might even just be the wire attached to the breaker is loose.

Comment: @Harper -- the warm could be derating the breaker's thermal trip though

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Good point! It would do that!

Comment: Warm is probably normal. Hot is not. If you can't put your finger on it and leave it there for a few seconds then it is overheating. Breakers are rated for 75° C which is 167°F That's pretty dang warm. But you should be able to touch for a few seconds it without ill effects.

Comment: @ArchonOSX -- yeah, 40degC is the cutoff point for the thermal trip derate (at least if you ask SqD)

Comment: If you had a reputable company install a new system the circuit breaker should have been part of their installation. If the wiring or the circuit breaker is not sized or installed correctly I would call them back to fix their mistakes. The whole job includes the wiring, and electrical delivery, plus  the installation and set up of the new unit.

Answer (score 1):

If the breaker is sized accordingly for the system running on it, then no, it should not be tripping. That said, yes, breakers can wear out. How old is the breaker?

Next question, Does the wiring for the A/C near the box feel warm? It really should not. If it does, I suspect a loose connection or HIGH resistance connection between the A/C and the breaker. It is possible the wiring in the panel is loose, but the HVAC company should have checked that.

Did the old unit trip as well? it is a sign something is wrong with the wiring or the breaker, and if you told the HVAC company that, then they should have checked or one of you called an electrician before connecting the circuit.

Comment: What's more, if it's a plain breaker in a currently made panel, *breakers are cheap*.  Like $8 for a BR or Homeline 2-pole 15-70A.

Answer (score 1):

I know I sound like a broke record, but you need to put an amprobe on it and see what kind of amperage you are actually pulling. Is it higher than the rating of the circuit breaker? If it is then you need to change out the breaker to the required size. Your unit should have a nameplate on it. It should give you a FLA (full load amperage) or a RLA (run load amperage). It will also give you a MOCP (maximum overcurrent current protection) which is the largest size of the breaker you should be installing.

The bad news might be that if you are increasing the size of the overcurrent protection, do you need to increase the size of your feeder conductors.

Of course if your amprobe is showing you are pulling the correct amount of current for the circuit then you probably do have a worn out breaker and you should replace it.

One last note: If the unit is tripping on startup the NEC will allow you to increase the breaker size to handle the surge at the start, and not increase your feeder size, but you should never go higher than the MOCP as that would void any warranty on equipment and could cause a possible hazard.

Good luck and stay safe